# Convert GPU hosted buffer to 3D-image with minimum data copying in OpenCL

Tags: memory-management, buffer, textures, opencl

**In short:**

I want to use data stored in GPU buffer as GPU image (3D-texture), if possible, without allocating the memory twice and wasting time by copying the data.

**More details:**

I have two kernels:

1. First kernel which produce 3D force-field and store it in buffer hosted in GPU memory. I used `clCreateBuffer()` to allocate this buffer.
2. Second kernel sample force from this force-field at random locations, therefore I use 3D image (allocated by `clCreateImage3D()`) so that is can use fast gpu-accelerated texture sampling interpolation and border-wrapping. `read_imagef()` and `sampler_t sampler_wrf =  CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_TRUE  | CLK_ADDRESS_MIRRORED_REPEAT | CLK_FILTER_LINEAR;`

It would be great if I can convert the buffer produced by kernel (1) into image3D without copying the data and without double-allocation of the GPU memory. The data already are in GPU memory, so I see no point in copying them. Maybe there is a way to just re-interpret the handle `cl_mem` from buffer to image while keeping the data untouched?

**In other words / code:**

Now I do it like this:

```
cl_mem buffer_1 = clCreateBuffer ( ... );
cl_mem image_1  = clCreateImage3D( ... );
clSetKernelArg( krenel_1, ... , &buffer_1 ); 
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( ..., krenel_1, ... );
clEnqueueCopyBufferToImage( ..., buffer_1, ..., image_1  );
clSetKernelArg( krenel_2, ... , &image_1 ); 
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( ..., krenel_2, ... );
```

Is there better / simpler / more *efficient way? By *efficient I mean faster and using less GPU memory.

=======================================

EDIT: I tried to make kernel which writes directly to texture. But does not work. Keep getting error
`CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS" (-52)` when enque the kernell, (clSetKernel Arg() pass without error )

Not sure if this is hardware specific (I have nVidia RTX 2060, driver 515.65.01 on Ubuntu 2022LTS)

cl code (GPU side):

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_3d_image_writes : enable

__kernel void write_toImg(
  __write_only image3d_t  imgOut
){
    const int ia = get_global_id(0);
    const int ib = get_global_id(1);
    const int ic = get_global_id(2);
    write_imagef( imgOut, (int4){ia,ib,ic,0}, (float){0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0} );
}
```

C/C++ code (CPU side):

```
cl_image_format imageFormat={CL_RGBA, CL_FLOAT};
cl_mem itexFF = clCreateImage3D(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, &imageFormat, nImg[0],nImg[1],nImg[2], 0, 0, 0, &err);

size_t global_size[4]{nImg[0],nImg[1],nImg[2],0};
size_t local_size [4]{1,1,1,0};
clSetKernelArg( current_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &itexFF) );
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( commands, current_kernel, 3, NULL, global_size, local_size, 0, NULL, NULL );
```

Comment: Why not have the kernel write the force field directly to the image?

Comment: isn't there some limitations that images can be either read-only or write-only ?

Comment: You can't have a single kernel read and write to the same image. But you can have a single kernel write to the image while another reads from it.

Comment: I keep getting `CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS" (-52)` when I try to run kernel which contains
`write_imagef( imgOut, (int4){ia,ib,ic,0}, (float){0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0} );` and have argument `__write_only image3d_t  imgOut`